# python, all values got broken to pieces when trying to merge lists within list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have lists of id within list like this:

> [[1347,1805371369,1805371401,1805371409,1805371424,1805371434,1805371462],[1805371691,1805371699,1805371712,1805371715,1805371725,1805371742,1917952665]']

I am trying to merge them to a list to look like this:

> [1347,1805371369,1805371401,1805371409,1805371424,1805371434,1805371462,1805371691,1805371699,1805371712,1805371715,1805371725,1805371742,1917952665']

but my result become something like this and I am not sure why:

```
['1','3','4','7',',','1','8','0','5','3','7','1','3','6','9'.......']']
```

I have tried the methods of itertools , flat and using for loop but they all gave me the same thing so I think something is wrong with list itself, but I am not really sure what. Please help

```
import itertools    
r=[[1347,1805371369,1805371401,1805371409,1805371424,1805371434,1805371462],[1805371691,1805371699,1805371712,1805371715,1805371725,1805371742,1917952665]]
merged = list(itertools.chain(*r))
print(merged)
```

actual code:

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import itertools

url='https://www.example.com/api/rest/1.1/etl/surveyresponses/ids/'
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded",'Authorization': "Bearer ******-****-****-****-*********"}
start_date = "2016-01-01"
stop_date = "2016-01-08"
endDate = "2016-02-014"
orgid='****'
r=[]
#Can only call 7 days at once, need to call the API multiple time and combine the result together for another API call 
while stop_date < endDate:
    start = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d") + timedelta(days=7) 
    stop = datetime.strptime(stop_date, "%Y-%m-%d") + timedelta(days=7) 
    start_date=start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    stop_date=stop.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    if stop_date>datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):
            stop_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    req_url=url+start_date+'/'+stop_date+'/'+orgid

    result =requests.get(req_url, headers=headers)
    r.append(result.text)



merged = list(itertools.chain(*r))
```

Comment: why is there a single `'` far at the end?`is it a string of a list-repr? if so , where is the beginning one?

Comment: Your code is not syntactically valid. Please copy and paste the *exact* code that gives the unwanted output.  (I suspect your real code creates a list of strings rather than a list of lists.)

Comment: I think you have an apostrophe `'` at the end of the list **r**. remove it and the program works fine.

Comment: The apostrophe is a typo(sorry) You guys are right the first code is just a sample output, and not the actual code. I have edited the post to include my actual code for the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I realized that I just need to change

r.append(result.text)

to

r.append(result.json())

then everything works lol

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray quotation mark at the end of your list definition. After taking it out and running your code, it worked fine for me. It's between the two closing brackets.

Comment: I wasn't sure either. I'm new to stack exchange and trying to answer the questions that I can answer -- is this just a "bad question" so I shouldn't answer it at all?

Comment: I think that might be it. Just a heads up: a lot of people on this site spend a disproportionate amount of time policing others rather than actually helping people. As such, there's a lot of unwritten implicit landmines that you can step on. Don't let it get to you! :)

Comment: @AyaMaguire: It would be much better if you also post the corrected code..makes easy for future users!!

Comment: your answer was downvoted by me because you are assuming ... from the usage and the output the OP posted it is clear he is operationg on strings - not on numbers. I mentioned the stray `'` as comment about 3 minutes before you answered. Your solution does not work, because he does not use a list of numbers. he is operating on something other wich is unclear - and unclear questions should be commented, clarified and then answered.